# Events in Custom Class

Tags: vb.net, class, events

I have a Class with a Treeview with (Two Elements Add, Subtract).

The Class has 4 properties:

- No1 (number)
- No2 (number)
- result (number)
- Treeview (the treeview).

In the Class, I want to get the result based on what is selected on treeview. For example, if 'Add' is selected, it should do add. I assume this should tie to **AfterSelect** event of the Treeview.

Is it possible?

Comment: ***"Is it possible"*** well yes it is. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in one step. I have used a 2 step appraoch... I created another variable in the class to store the treeview selection (this method has to be called in the code as myclass.GetTreeViewNode and then call the event myclass.DoCalc.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.  Have your class handle the `AfterSelect` event of the `TreeView`.

Comment: Are you storing a reference to the **actual TreeView** in your class?  What should happen in `DoCalc()` if nothing is selected?  This seems a really bad design if you're doing it that way.  One option would be to store some kind of current operation **flag** (possibly an `enum` value) in your class that determines what to do.  Then you'd update the current operation when the TreeView is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am actually storing the reference to actual Treeview in the class. Will follow you advise on the flag for current operation.

How do I reference to the AfterSelect event of the Treeview within the class. Currently I am referencing to it at the instance of the class.

Comment: Any time you hook an event, you create a link between the object and the event. If the same treeview is being used across multiple class instances, you'll create many links and everytime the treeview **AfterSelect** is run, you'll call that code in every class. You may want to consider changing things around to have only one **AfterSelect** to run. Cannot help more without more information about your classes and code.